# CheckBox is not accepting state change in the code

Tags: .net, winforms, checkbox, oxygene

On a winform I have a three different checkboxes. They all won't accept any changes to their state programmatically but only by a mouse click. Why?

[image]

Here is how I am setting their state in my code:

```
 if i=1 then
  ClientChk.Checked := true
 else
  ClientChk.Checked := false;

 if i = 2 then
  HostChk.Checked := true
 else
  HostChk.Checked := false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've posted code with no context, and expect us to try and psychically debug it for you. I'll give it a shot, but you really need to learn to make your questions more complete.

My guess is that somewhere in the code you didn't post, you're enabling/disabling `ClientChk` and `HostChk` based on whether the `Enable Remote Mode` box is checked, and when it's not checked (as in your image), the `ClientChk` and `HostChk` buttons are disabled. A quick trip through your code (or using the debugger) would tell in very quickly if that's the problem.

You can improve your code somewhat, BTW (and handle enabling/disabling them based on the value of `EnableRemoteChk`:

```
ClientChk.Enabled := EnableRemoteChk.Checked;
HostChk.Enabled := ClientChk.Enabled;
if ClientChk.Enabled then
begin
  ClientChk.Checked := (i = 1);
  HostChk.Checked := (i = 2);
end;
```